# Is it possible to display ReportViewer in cshtml (RDLC) using C# on .NET Core v5 or v6?

Tags: asp.net-core, dynamic-rdlc-generation

Is it possible to display ReportViewer (RDLC) in a `.cshtml` view using C# on .NET v5 or v6? Many thanks.

I want to display it as aspx (`ReportViewer` component).

Comment: Unlikely. Are there any reasons you cannot use .NET Framework?

Comment: oh in .Net framwork, i can view used aspx page, but when convert to Netcore. aspx not use ?

Comment: Web RDLC, for now, only officially supported on .NET Framework. ,NET Core / .NET 5 version's RDLC are third parties and have a lot of issues.

Comment: yes. i am using third party but it only export pdf to view , do not viewer on cshtml.

Comment: You can't use ReportViewer without .aspx page. If you must, you can use `iframe` in your cshtml page and set the `src` link to your report hosted elsewhere.

Comment: I dont know why crytal do not support on NetCore Not yet ?

Comment: I don't know neither. I would guess that .NET Core / .NET 5 are not mature enough for them to invest resources to develop a updated version. You can see [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core), the LTS for these .NET version may not worth the efforts. While .NET Framework, as of now, has no [end date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework).

Comment: Net 4.8 will be end date after 3 year. i think Netcore base on other teach so they dont invest resources to dev it... My project converted netcore but report process different direction.